# why I can not imshow image in one thread with nameWindow in another thread?

Tags: c++, opencv

I do nameWindow in father thread(main routine), then I start to show my image with imshow in son thread, however, I can not go on, it is locked!!! why ???

```
void task()
{
    cv::VideoCapture cap("video.mp4");
    cv::Mat src;
    while (true)
    {
        cap.read(src);
        cv::imshow("src", src);
        cv::waitKey(1);
    }
}

int main()
{       
    cv::namedWindow("src", WINDOW_NORMAL);
    boost::threadpool::pool pl(2);
    pl.schedule(&task);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is locked on when you pause your debugger? imshow? waitkey? or something else?

Comment: debugger!!!  Precisely, I set many Breakpoints, but it happened nothing, and I could not get any show image, I tried to see the parallel threads, they all stop at one place for long time

Comment: Threads + GUI -> ample opportunities to shoot yourself in the foot. Generally, keep all the GUI interactions in a single thread (at least until you really understand the intricacies of the underlying GUI backend).

Comment: thanks!!! I read some source code of opencv. I got  something interesting, the system really does some important things to maintain the name of image show